# Did the shellshock bash fix break basic command line tools like echo and cat?

Tags: bash, shellshock

I used to be able to do things like:

```
X=123 cat <<EOF
X is $X
EOF
```

or even simpler:

```
X=123 echo $X
```

The first one still seems to work on Mac OS X after install the bash fix, however neither seem to work on my Ubuntu 14.04 instance in AWS anymore. What makes it that `echo` or `cat` no longer have access to these environment variables? Stranger still, when I pass the env vars to a NodeJS app I don't seem to have any issues:

```
cat <<EOF > test.js
console.log('X is ' + process.env.X);
EOF
X=123 node test.js
```

This seems to work in bash scripts as well:

```
cat <<EOF > test.sh
echo X is \$X
EOF
chmod +x test.sh
X=123 ./test.sh
```

Comment: `X=123 echo $X` should never have worked. Have you looked at the `test.sh` file that you created? Does it say `echo X is $X` or does it say `echo X is `?

Comment: You're absolutely right, the shell was stripping out $X since it was evaluating it. I've updated the question to reflect that (basically it works in Mac OS X, not in Ubuntu).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In any POSIX shell, when you write

```
X=123 echo $X
```

the `$X` is expanded before the whole command is executed, i.e. if `$X` is initially unset, you get:

```
X=123 echo
```

which is then executed. You can see more or less what the shell is doing with `set -x`:

```
$ set -x
$ X=123 echo X=$X
+ X=123
+ echo X=
X=
$ set +x
```

You can see that `echo` (actually the shell itself, which does the expansion before executing `echo`) still has access to the environment:

```
$ X=123 eval 'echo $X'
123
```

The issue with `cat <<EOF` is similar. Note that concerning `bash`, there was a bug in old versions (before 4.1), described in the `CHANGES` file as:

> Fixed a bug that caused variable expansion in here documents to look in any temporary environment.

This may be the cause of the behavior observed under Mac OS X. Do not rely on this bug.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome explanation! I'm still stumped by why the `cat <<EOF` works in Mac OS X bash and not in Ubuntu. Any ideas?

Comment: Probably worth adding to that code a "set +x" to stop debugging.

Comment: @AbdullahJibaly The behavior under Mac OS X is probably due to a bug in old bash versions (now fixed). See my edited answer.

Answer (score 6):

Your questions regarding the here-documents are probably unrelated. The thing is, `bash` will perform the expansions and the assignment concurrently - so a leading `X=123...` should not affect the value expanded from within the here-document. This is because the here-document is an input file-descriptor that `bash` must build and pass to `cat` upon invocation in the same way it must assign `123` to `$X` before passing that plus the rest of its environment off to `cat` at `execve` time.

Consider:

```
X=321; X=123 bash <<HEREDOC
echo "$X is not yet \$X and $$ is not yet \$$."
HEREDOC
```

#### OUTPUT

```
321 is not yet 123 and 17134 is not yet 17225.
```