# Why is variable assignment preceding command ignored?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, command

The bash 4.1 manpage states *(emphasis added)*...

> **Simple Commands**
>
> A simple command is ***a sequence of optional variable assignments
>   followed by blank-separated words*** and redirections, and terminated by
>   a control operator. The first **word** specifies the command to be
>   executed, and is passed as argument zero. The remaining words are
>   passed as arguments to the invoked command.

Verifying the version on my system *(NOT patched for shellshock)*...

```
#  bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.1.0(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu) ...
```

However, preceding variable assignments, without semicolons, are supposed to be a way to localize environment variable values for the life of that one command invocation only, but do not seem to ...

```
#  x=123 echo $x; unset x; echo $x
bash: x: unbound variable
#  x=123; echo $x; unset x; echo $x
123
bash: x: unbound variable
#  x=123; echo $x | tr '1' 'a'; unset x; echo $x
a23
bash: x: unbound variable
#  x=123 echo $x | tr '1' 'a'; unset x; echo $x
bash: x: unbound variable
bash: x: unbound variable
#  x="123" echo "$x" | tr '1' 'a'; unset x; echo $x
bash: x: unbound variable
bash: x: unbound variable
#  x="123"; echo "$x" | tr '1' 'a'; unset x; echo $x
a23
bash: x: unbound variable
```

**Solution**
Per [this answer from another question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/56454/27437) it appears that the command must deliberately use the environment variables of its parent and `echo` does not. But shell invocations like `bash -c` do ...

```
x=123 bash -c 'echo $x'; unset x; echo $x
123
bash: x: unbound variable
```

**Resources**

- [This answer says it should behave I understand it to though it does not ...](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/86798)
- [This may be the answer ...](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/56454/27437)

Comment: Because you are mixing two things - setting a variable in the environment of a command and expanding it by shell on the command line. See the same question with different wording: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56444/how-do-i-set-an-environment-variable-on-the-command-line-and-have-it-appear-in-c.

Comment: Oddly related: [Did the shellshock bash fix break basic command line tools like echo and cat?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159925/80216) See also [In bash, how I define a “command scope” variable?](http://superuser.com/q/801822/354511)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line

```
x=123 echo $x
```

is evaluated in the following order:

1. `$x` is expanded to the value of `x` in the *current* shell.
2. The value of `x` in the environment of the command to be executed is set to 123
3. The expanded command line is searched for a command, and `echo` is found.
4. `echo` is run in an environment where `x` is set to 123, and `$1` is set to
   whatever value `x` had in step 1.
5. `echo` outputs `$1` to standard output, but otherwise ignores the other values
   in its environment.

Note that `$x` as an argument is separate from the `x` that precedes the command.